# Get-WmiObject - Use OR-Operator in -filter?

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I have to do some powershell script modifications which I cannot test properly on my dev machine.

Thats why I would like to know, if I can use an `OR`-Operator in my `Get-WmiObject -filter` operation?

Currently we use

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name like 'ApplicationName1 Client%'" ...).Uninstall()
```

But lately we renamed the name of the application from `ApplicationName1` to `NewName`. Thats why I would like to add another condition like this:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name like 'ApplicationName1 Client%' OR Name like 'NewName Client%'" ...).Uninstall()
```

**My question would be:**

Is this a valid syntax for the filter or would this throw an exception / give an error? If it gives an error, how would you do this?

Comment: Has the thought to just try it occured to you?

Comment: "I have to do some powershell script modifications which I cannot test properly on my dev machine."

Comment: Seriously? You write scripts based on the statements of others and run them in a production environment without testing? Your line runs on every windows machine that has a powershell, by removing the `.Uninstall()` statement you can test the output quite safely. And it takes less time than even writing a question here.

Comment: Well, ofcourse it would go into test lab first. But building a package for the test lab is taking a bit of time and I thought, it would be better to just make sure. Anyways, I already got my confirmation, thats all I wanted to have ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is valid syntax

for example

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product -filter "Name Like 'citrix%' OR name like 'Microsoft%'"
```

Would give every product that starts with Citrix AND every product that starts with Microsoft