# Get-WmiObject -Filter OR not working with NULL

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql, get-wmiobject

These cmdlets work:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriver -Filter "DriverProviderName <> NULL"
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriver -Filter "DriverProviderName <> 'Microsoft'"
```

I can't seem to combine them with a OR statement & I don't know why:
`Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriver -Filter "DriverProviderName <> 'Microsoft' OR DriverProviderName <> NULL"`

The command above runs, but doesn't exclude the NULL entries last one is Fax on my Win10 PC.

[The answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862024/1575219) seems to imply I have it marked right, however theirs is matching to a string whereas I need to exclude a NULL object. I suspect it has to do with the NULL and/or lack of single quotes.

Comment: The ```-Filter``` expects a WQL “where” expression - try ```IS NULL``` / ```IS NOT NULL``` per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-operators

Comment: `-Filter "DriverProviderName <> 'Microsoft' and DriverProviderName IS NOT NULL"` if you want to exclude the NULL entries… Note the `AND` connective…

Comment: Thanks for both of your feedback. `-Filter` does work with `<>`. @JosefZ comment was the solution using `AND` instead of `OR`. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: AND not OR.  OR allows either case, like TRUE OR FALSE = TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about [translating from English sentences into logical form](https://www.csm.ornl.gov/%7Esheldon/ds/ex1.1.2.html): *When translating from English sentences into logical form, …, and the phrase "`neither A nor B`" is translated as "`not A and not B`".* Use

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriver -Filter `
  "DriverProviderName <> 'Microsoft' AND DriverProviderName IS NOT NULL"
```

Note: see [Translating “neither…nor” into a mathematical logical expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25091/) as well; applying [de Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), the following code surprisingly works although uses *undocumented* `NOT` logical operator in a [WQL query](https://powershell.one/wmi/wql):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPSignedDriver -Filter `
  "NOT (DriverProviderName = 'Microsoft' OR DriverProviderName IS NULL)"
```

In above PowerShell code examples is used a [backtick to split commands over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608144/) for better readability…

Comment: `<> NULL` works for me.  Using AND is the important part.